# Counting the number of individual letters in a string in R

Tags: r, string, character

I have the following string of characters:

```
pig<-c("A","B","C","D","AB","ABC","AB","AA","CD","CA",NA)
```

I am trying to get R to tell me how many of each total letters there are and how many total NAs there are.  Thus, in this case I would like to the result to look like this:

```
print(cow)
A  B  C  D  NA
6  3  4  2  1
```

I have tried `table` in combination with `strsplit` but cannot figure out exactly how to do it.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use `NULL` (or the empty character `""`) for the `split` value in `strsplit()`, then unlist it.  Then, in `table()` you'll want to use the `useNA` argument to include any `NA` values.  Here we'll use `"ifany"`, so that if there are any `NA` values they will be shown in the table and if there are not, `NA` will not be shown in the result at all.

```
table(unlist(strsplit(pig, NULL)), useNA = "ifany")
#
#   A    B    C    D <NA> 
#   7    4    4    2    1
```